# csrf token codeigniter dropzone

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, csrf, dropzone

I have tried to send csrf token codeigniter with dropzone, but it gives the error 'The action you have requested is not allowed'. can you help me for fix send csrf token, thanks

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var img= '<?= $min_images?>';
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#my-dropzone", {
        url: "<?= base_url("agribisnis/do_upload") ?>",
        acceptedFiles: "image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/png",
        maxFilesize: 0.5,
        maxFiles:img,
        uploadMultiple: false
    }
);
myDropzone.on('sending', function(file, xhr, formData) {
    /* ini kalo pakai csrf di codeigniter */
    formData.append("<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>","<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>");
});
```

Comment: What is the output of each of these : `<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>` and `<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>` ?

Comment: Look at the request in Dev tools and see if it's sending the csrf token along with the image

Comment: @HastaDhana output from `<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?> and <?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>`  different with response header csrf_cookie,

Comment: @Alex  csrf token result from sending csrf token is different with result csrf response from response header

Comment: set regen to false: `$config['csrf_regenerate'] = FALSE;` doesn't play well with ajax. let me know if fixed

Comment: @Alex yeap, but if set regen to false, key token csrf is same for all form and ajax sir, i has tried for this,

Comment: That&#39;s the nature of csrf. It doesn&#39;t play well with ajax in ci. Best to keep Regen as false or exclude the URL.

Comment: @Alex oke sir, thanks you for information about csrf,

Comment: @BiyanVox what worked for me is to make a GET request when CSRF token expire so you can use the new one to then make the request

Comment: @SBA no, must be set $config['csrf_regenerate'] = FALSE;